# Add new column in existing csv file

Tags: java, android, csv

Can someone help me on how can i insert new values at the end of a specific line? i want to insert a value for the state saved or incorrect of each marker. The values should be inserted when i click on specific buttons from a dialog: Saved or Incorrect.

This is my CSV now:

```
   1,45.66680458,25.60458787
   2,45.66672655,25.6047773
   3,45.66670734,25.60465392
```

How it should be when i write in it:

```
   1,45.66680458,25.60458787,salvat
   2,45.66672655,25.6047773,salvat
   3,45.66670734,25.60465392,gresit
```

Updated and working code for state "saved" and "incorrect":

```
   bt_nu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onClick(View v) {

                                      marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                                      dialog.dismiss();
                                     String salvat = "salvat";


                                     BufferedReader br=null;
                                     BufferedWriter bw=null;
                                     final String lineSep=System.getProperty("line.separator");

                                     try {
                                         File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "fisier.csv");
                                         File file2 = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "fisier1.csv");//so the


                                         br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file))) ;
                                         bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file2)));
                                         String line = null;

                                         for ( line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine())
                                         {
                                             String[] RowData = line.split(",");
                                             Double latitudine = Double.valueOf(RowData[1]);
                                             Double longitudine = Double.valueOf(RowData[2]);
                                             if (latitudine == coords.latitude && longitudine == coords.longitude ) {
                                                 String addedColumn = String.valueOf(salvat);
                                                 bw.write(line + "," + addedColumn +lineSep);
                                             }
                                             else {
                                                 bw.write(line +  lineSep);
                                             }
                                             file2.renameTo(file);
                                         }

                                     }catch(Exception e){
                                         System.out.println(e);
                                     }finally  {
                                         if(br!=null) {
                                             try {
                                                 br.close();
                                             } catch (IOException e) {
                                                 e.printStackTrace();
                                             }
                                         }
                                         if(bw!=null) {
                                             try {
                                                 bw.close();
                                             } catch (IOException e) {
                                                 e.printStackTrace();
                                             }
                                         }
                                     }
                                     }
                                 }


    );
    bt_gresit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onClick(View v) {

                                     marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
                                     dialog.dismiss();
                                     String gresit = "gresit";

                                     BufferedReader br=null;
                                     BufferedWriter bw=null;
                                     final String lineSep=System.getProperty("line.separator");

                                     try {
                                         File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "fisier.csv");
                                         File file2 = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "fisier1.csv");//so the


                                         br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file))) ;
                                         bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file2)));
                                         String line = null;

                                         for ( line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine())
                                         {
                                             String[] RowData = line.split(",");
                                             Double latitudine = Double.valueOf(RowData[1]);
                                             Double longitudine = Double.valueOf(RowData[2]);
                                             if (latitudine == coords.latitude && longitudine == coords.longitude ) {
                                                 String addedColumn = String.valueOf(gresit);
                                                 bw.write(line + "," + addedColumn+lineSep);

                                             }
                                             else {
                                                 bw.write(line + lineSep);
                                             }
                                             file2.renameTo(file);
                                         }

                                     }catch(Exception e){
                                         System.out.println(e);
                                     }finally  {
                                         if(br!=null) {
                                             try {
                                                 br.close();
                                             } catch (IOException e) {
                                                 e.printStackTrace();
                                             }
                                         }
                                         if(bw!=null) {
                                             try {
                                                 bw.close();
                                             } catch (IOException e) {
                                                 e.printStackTrace();
                                             }
                                         }
                                     }

                                 }

                                 }
```

Comment: CSV means **Comma**-Separated Values. You data doesn't seem to be comma-separated. Is the data **tab**-separated, perhaps?

Comment: Don't create the `FileOutputStream` inside the line-reading loop. Create it outside the loop, make it write to different file, the delete the old and rename the new when done.

Comment: maybe it is because of how i paste the content here. but the file it is for sure a CSV. with the code above i just succeeded to write at the end of the file

Comment: No, you very specifically pasted in tab-separated text as the file content. And read my second comment for how to fix "append to end of file" issue.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try it. Although i was looking into avoiding creating a new file and than replace the old one.

Comment: Impossible avoid, because as soon as you try to overwrite a line that is longer than existing line, the overflow will overwrite the beginning of the next file in the file. --- Well, unless you read the *entire* file into memory, change the content, then write is all back. In that case, you won't lose data.

Comment: i Have tried this method but i only get to write one line in the new file. I need the new CSV to have all the old values. The value "gresit" needs to be inserted only for a specific line. Can you please help me?

Comment: You're creating a *new file*, i.e. a modified copy, so you need to write all lines you want to keep. If you don't write a line, it's because you wanted to delete that line in the copy. So, any line you don't want to modify or delete must be written unchanged.

Comment: Ok so i was managed to do something (i have updated the code) but right now i am just adding a new column with every value i enter. And i need to have all the new values on only one column as i will use them after. Can you please help me with this? sorry but i am kind of new to programming

Comment: No need anymore. I managed to solve it. Thank you though for your guiding so far.